# Use form to send ajax request to rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

This should be simple enough but I don't understand forms without changing a model entry.

I want to do this:

Have a text entry field (or drop down menu) where a user can set the number of rows he wants to limit a table to

Currently I display all the rows with a loop but if somebody types "3" in the box and hits the button the partial that renders the table `_table.html.erb` should reload with a limit of three applied.

How would I set this up?

Comment: Is this form remote? Also, what is shown in the table partial?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

In your javascript file:

```
$('#my_button').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url: '/table',
    data:{ rows: $('#my_text_field').val() },
    success: function(data){
      $('#my_table_container').html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

In your controller:

```
def table
  render partial: 'table', locals: { rows: params[:rows] }
end
```

In your routes.rb:

```
match 'table' => 'your_controller#table'
```

And then in your partial (_partial.html.rb), you have to iterate over number of rows that you receive in the rows param.

Comment: could you build in a params.merge? I have other params that govern sortings etc and would like them to stay the way they are

Comment: If you need more params from the view, just add them in the "data ajax attribute" like `data:{ rows: val1, sort: val2 }`